# SharePoint 2010 Windows Authentication User Interface

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

The company I work for currently services 13 School districts who all authenticate through different active directories to our SharePoint 2010 site. We are currently looking for a way to switch the user interface for logging in. I was wondering if there is anyway of changing the Windows Authentication dialog box, to look like a form, without using forms or claims based authentication. We are also trying to avoid using mixed authentication. 
So I was wondering, is there any way to change the look and feel of how users log in without switching the authentication type from windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to do this is via Forms Authentication using Active Directory as the authentication source.